# Show Online Video Duration In GridView

Tags: android

I am using an FTP Client to get videos from a server and show them on a gridview. I would like to display duration of each gridview item (videos) as well.

I have tried using this code outside of the gridview adapter:

```
            for (FTPFile file : files) {

                if (file.isFile())
                {
                    //GetDuration
                    try{
                        //NOTE: must not use https
                        mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
                        mmr.setDataSource(myDomain+skyVideos+"/"+username+"/"+file.getName());
                        long duration =Long.parseLong(mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
                        duration=duration/1000;
                        long minute=duration/(60);
                        long second=duration-(minute*60);
                        mmr.release();

                        strDuration = String.format("%02d:%02d" , minute, second);

                        //ALL VIEWS
                        for (int j = 0; j < gv.getChildCount(); j++) {
                            View child = gv.getChildAt(j);
                            holder.tvDuration = child.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);                    

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    holder.tvDuration.setText(strDuration);
                                }
                            });
                        }


                        arrListStr_Duration.add(strDuration);
                        stringArr_Duration = new String[arrListStr_Duration.size()];
                        stringArr_Duration = arrListStr_Duration.toArray(stringArr_Duration);

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                      //
                    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }

                //SORT BY TIMESTAMP
                Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparing((FTPFile remoteFile) -> remoteFile.getTimestamp()).reversed());

            }
            client.disconnect();
```

This works fine, even though it sets duration (`holder.tvDuration.setText(strDuration);`) of videos one after the other and not all at the same time (because of how the for loop works?) even though I'm running this method in a background: (I can live with this though)

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //code in background here
                getFTP_Duration();

                getFTP_SizeArray();
            }
        }).start();
```

Anyway this all fine until the user starts scrolling before the arrListStr_Duration is fully populated then the duration will be set on the wrong video because the views get recycled.

Now in the GridView adapter I have tried the following in the `View getView` method:

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            holder = new Holder();

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_video_gridview_single_checkbox, null);
            }

            holder.ivImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            holder.tvInvisibleDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvInvisibleDate);
            holder.ivCheckbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCheckbox);
            holder.tvDuration = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
            holder.ibDots = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ibDots);
            holder.mypopupWindow = null;

            if (arrListStr_File.size() == arrListStr_Duration.size())
            {
                //Duration finished populating
                holder.tvDuration.setText(stringArr_Duration[position]);
            }
            else
            {
                //user scrolling while duration is still being populated
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < gv.getChildCount(); i++) {

                        if (arrListStr_Duration.size() != 0)
                        {

                            View child = gv.getChildAt(i);
                            holder.tvDuration = child.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);

                            try {
                                holder.tvDuration.setText(stringArr_Duration[i]);
                            }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                            {
                                //
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                    //
                }
            }
...
```

This will also mix up the duration and videos because `gv.getChildCount()` only returns count of what can be seen on screen and this count is reset when user scrolls because of recycling. When the user scrolls after the duration has been fully populated then there are no issues but of cause this happens in the background and user should be able to scroll whenever they want to and still have the correct duration set on the correct videos, how can I achieve this? I thought of not using recycling at all but I understand that this is bad for performance. Hope I made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation of adapter's getView()

```
* @param position The position of the item within the adapter's data set of the item whose view we want.

* @return A View corresponding to the data at the specified position.

View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
```

> When the user scrolls after the duration has been fully populated then there are no issues.>

This is because you are correctly using `position` in this case, whereas in other case you are using child index, that's why `GridView` is mixing up your videos.

Your entire `getView()` can be simplified by creating a method to get video duration.

```
 private String getVideoDuration(int index){
    if(index <= stringArr_Duration.length)
        return stringArr_Duration[index];
    return null; // can return empty string also here.
}
```

Then call it from `getView()` and pass `@param : position` to it, not the child index.

Comment: stringArr_Duration.length is null at the time of its call from getView() - FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever takes a bit of time to extract duration that's why, the method you proposed runs before the duration of videos can be fetched from the server

Comment: OK so I have modified your code and created a Global int variable to hold the position so that I can call the method again when it returns NullPointerException or ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, now this works fine except when I leave the activity to go to another one (I finish the activity) and then return back to it the duration is mixed up again but when launching the app from start everything works well, I don't get it since the activity was destroyed when I return to it then it should behave like I've launched the app from start when I start the activity? Do I make sense?

Comment: To summarize the above, when I launch the app and click on my VideoActivity your modified code works well, when I click on OtherActivty and return back to VideoActivity the duration becomes mixed up on some videos. When I close the app and run it from scratch and click on VideoActivity all is well, until I choose any other activity and then RETURN BACK to VideoActivity.

Comment: @param position is not supposed to be saved in global scope, and if stringArr_Duration is null then I think it means video's are not available yet, then there is no point in displaying its duration, so you can safely return empty string from my method.

Comment: The app crashes with NullPointerException when stringArr_Duration.length is empty so what I do is I catch this exception and call the method again, by the second or third time, the stringArr_Duration.length will not be null, then I catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because the array is not fully populated and call the method again until duration is set to all videos, this is the only way I can get it to work without crashing.

Comment: Oh man , I have seen use of exception handling in adapter first time in my life. You need to design your app, you can't leave your job to uncertainty of catching exception and hoping that it will work by second or third time.

Comment: then should I use a delay handler, the time to go to the server and fetch the metadata is slower than any action that happens within the app locally

Comment: Look you are fetching data in background thread, from that thread you need to post message to your UI thread and pass collected data.Then from UI thread you need to pass that data to your GridView adapter.

Comment: Try using AsyncTask for background job, it simplifies the use of threads and handlers

Comment: Thank you sir, after implementing AsyncTask your code has given my app a TURBO BOOST (although i don't quite understand it) but you really helped me a lot! I'll approve your awesome answer + an upvote.

Comment: Reason for TURBO BOOST : adapter's getView() is called whenever GridView needs to show an item (initial load as well as every time user scrolls). param position is passed and purposely kept 'final' to identify the corresponding View from underlying data set. Behind the scenes GridView will take this view and display it to you at @param position. So, this is no place for unnecessary processing and definitely not for exception handling.

Comment: I'll be reading up more on this and referencing back to your comments. Thanks again.